# R df process each column by a different function provided in a list of functions

Tags: r

I guess my problem is very simple, but I could not find the solution in web yet.
I would like to modify a data frame with a set of functions.
The functions are defined in a list. They may have more than one argument, but one arg is always the value found on the related column in a df.
I used build in BOD data set just for convinience. The list could be this:

```
funs <- list(
        fn1 = function(x) x+1,
        fn2 = function(x) x-1
)
```

The function call could look like this:

```
searchedFunc(BOD, funs)
```

So after modificatin Time column values are added by 1 and demand column values are subtracted by one.

Comment: See `?mapply`; `mapply(function(f, x) f(x), funs, BOD)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to be more flexible

```
funs <- list(
  fn1 = function(x) x+1,
  fn2 = function(x) x-1               
)

searchedFunc <- function(df, fns) {
  sapply(seq(along.with=fns), function(i) fns[[i]](df[, i]))
}

searchedFunc(BOD, funs)
```

Hope it helps,

alex